# Javascript document.write select option

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm new in Javascript and I'm just trying to change the word value printed on a webpage, I've the next code:

```
<select id="quantity">
    <option value="value1">1</option>
    <option value="value2">2</option>
</select> 
<p id="p1">Change Value </p>
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("quantity");
    var y=x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML=y;
</script>
```

What I want is to change the written word when the select option changes.
Thanks.

Comment: Learn about event handling: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html, http://www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript. And don't use `document.write`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you have not binded the change action for the drop down to a function. Give this a try :

```
var x = document.getElementById("quantity");
var updateField = function() {
    var y=x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML=y; 
}
x.onchange = updateField;
updateField();
```

[here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mG3b4/) of this code

You can [read more about event listeners here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Comment: You can simplify the whole body of the handler to `document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = this.value`. But then you have to change the last function call to `x.onchange()` instead. http://jsfiddle.net/mG3b4/1/ It's certainly simpler than `var y=x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;`

Comment: That's what I needed, also with this example I learned something about updates and event listeners. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The script that have will be run when the page loads, I guess that you need to create a function to do this script which will be called when the selection changes.

like   `<select onchange="jsFunction()">`

Answer (score 0):

Use `addEventListener` to attach an event externally:

```
var myEl = document.getElementById('quantity');

myEl.addEventListener('change', function() {
   var x = document.getElementById("quantity");
   var y=x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
   document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML=y;
}, false);
```

`addEventListener` is the way to register an event listener as specified in W3C DOM. Its benefits are as follows:

- It allows adding more than a single handler for an event. This is particularly useful for DHTML libraries or Mozilla extensions that need to work well even if other libraries/extensions are used.
- It gives you finer-grained control of the phase when the listener gets activated (capturing vs. bubbling).
- It works on any DOM element, not just HTML elements.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/g522P/3/)

Comment: *"It works on any DOM element, not just HTML elements."* Do you mean SVG? Or which other DOM elements are you talking about?

Comment: any DOM elements includes XML and java DOM elements..Though the syntax varies in all of those..

Comment: Well, DOM is DOM. Once you parsed the source, be it XML or HTML (or something else), you don't really have to distinguish where the DOM was created from. But you are right, the interface that defines `getElementByID` is independent from any specific markup (http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html). I was asking because there are in fact extensions to DOM which only apply to HTML, but this is not one of them.

Comment: I agree with your point that there is no difference once it is parsed.